# Can Dagger Perform Injection of view Objects in Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am Exploring [**Dagger**](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2) for the dependency injection in Android 
.

**What I discovered:**

- We can inject `SharedPreferences`
- We can inject `services`
- We can inject `Retrofit` Instances

---

**Questions:**

What I am trying to find:

1. Can we inject view objects like `ImageView`, `Button` etc?
2. If possible how to perform it?
3. If not possible what is the best alternative (I am aware Roboguice is deprecated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we inject view objects like `ImageView`, `Button` etc?

Since you mentioned Roboguice as a point of reference in your question, I am taking this question to mean can you do something the following in Dagger 2:

```
@InjectView(R.id.my_view) View view;
```

The answer to this question is 'no'. In other words, Dagger 2 includes no special syntax for injecting Views that would otherwise be obtained through `findViewById(int id)`.

> If not possible what is the best alternative (I am aware Roboguice is deprecated)?

[Butterknife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) is a good companion to Dagger 2 in that it uses the same approach of code generation to allow you to inject views.

Alternatively, the [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) will allow you to do this.